# Mailchimp API error - Bad Request on code that has always worked

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We recently switched to a new server and now all of the sudden I'm getting an error with mailchimp's send campaign endpoint.

The campaign gets created with no issue but it's just sending that comes back with the following error. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

```
    <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;640be8ac&#46;1610827794&#46;1757979e
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Below is my PHP code

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$this->oauthData['oauth_api_endpoint'].'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/'.$campaignID.'/actions/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
                    'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json',
                    'Authorization: OAuth ' . $this->oauthData['oauth_token']
            ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $cuseragnet);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to pass through an empty array

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array()));
```